# Join Json Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an html list that look like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Menu</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="Save">Save</button>
        <ol class="example">
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-image" data-toggle="popover"></i>
                <span contenteditable="true" onclick="this.focus();"> m1</span>
                <ol class="">
                    <li data-formid="ACC:ACC01" data-formdesc="Account" contenteditable="true" onclick="this.focus();" class="">Account (ACC:ACC01)<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-2x move_right"></i></li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            <li>
                <i class="fa fa-image" data-toggle="popover"></i>
                <span contenteditable="true" onclick="this.focus();"> m2</span>
                <ol class="">
                    <li data-formid="ACC:ACC05" data-formdesc="Account Details Listing" contenteditable="true" onclick="this.focus();" class="">Account Details Listing (ACC:ACC05)<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right fa-2x move_right"></i></li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Save").click(function() {
                MenuID = '1';
                var Item = [];
                var MenuItems = []; // used to store list item into an array
                var jsonItemParent = {}; // used to store parent list in JSON Object
                var jsonItemChild = {}; // used to store child list in JOSON Object
                var jsonMenuItems = []; // used to store Object of JSON parent list and cild list
                var li = $('ol.example:last > li').length;

                $('ol.example:last > li').each(function(i,e){
                    if($(this).children('ol').children('li').length >= 1){
                        $(this).children('ol').children('li').each(function(ii,ee){

                            var parentOfChild = $(this).parent().prev().text().trim();
                            var child = $(this).text().trim();
                            var ItemIDofParent = MenuID+'0'+(i+1);
                            var ItemIDofChild = MenuID+'0'+(i+1)+'-'+0+(ii+1);

                            var FormIDofParent = ($(this).parent().prev().data('formid'))?$(this).parent().prev().data('formid'):'';
                            var FormIDofChild = ($(this).data('formid'))?$(this).data('formid'):'';

                            // Icon:
                            var IconofParent = ($(this).parent().prev().prev().attr('class'))?$(this).parent().prev().prev().attr('class').trim():'';
                            var IconofChild = ($(this).attr('[class="fa"]'))?$(this).attr('class'):'';

                            // Item Parent
// Store each item into Item array
                            Item.push(MenuID);
                            Item.push(ItemIDofParent);
                            Item.push(parentOfChild);
                            Item.push(IconofParent);
                            Item.push(FormIDofParent);
                            Item.push('');
                            Item.push('N');
                            MenuItems.push(Item);

 // Convert list properties in JSON
                            jsonItemParent.ID = MenuID;
                            jsonItemParent.ItemID=ItemIDofParent;
                            jsonItemParent.ItemDesc=parentOfChild;
                            jsonItemParent.Icon=IconofParent;
                            jsonItemParent.Form=FormIDofParent;
                            jsonItemParent.Parents='';
                            jsonItemParent.Active='Y';
                            jsonMenuItems.push(jsonItemParent);


                            // Item Child
// Same as list parent above, this is for list child
                            Item.push(MenuID);
                            Item.push(ItemIDofChild);
                            Item.push(child);
                            Item.push(IconofChild);
                            Item.push(FormIDofChild);
                            Item.push(ItemIDofParent);
                            Item.push('Y');
                            MenuItems.push(Item);

                            jsonItemChild.ID = MenuID;
                            jsonItemChild.ItemID=ItemIDofChild;
                            jsonItemChild.ItemDesc=child;
                            jsonItemChild.Icon=IconofChild;
                            jsonItemChild.Form=FormIDofChild;
                            jsonItemChild.Parents=ItemIDofParent;
                            jsonItemChild.Active='Y';
                            jsonMenuItems.push(jsonItemChild);               
                        })
                    }else{
                        /*
                            Perform action if a list has no child
                        */
                    }

                });
                console.log(jsonItemParent);
                console.log(jsonItemChild);
                console.log(jsonMenuItems);
                console.log(MenuItems);
            });
        })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

From above script, tried to get each of list properties and put them into an array, then I tried to convert it into JSON Obj.
`console.log(MenuItems);` return a result of array like this

```
0: (28) ["1", "101", "m1", "fa fa-image", "", "", "N", "1", "101-01", "Account (ACC:ACC01)", "", "ACC:ACC01", "101", "Y", "1", "102", "m2", "fa fa-image", "", "", "N", "1", "102-01", "Account Details Listing (ACC:ACC05)", "", "ACC:ACC05", "102", "Y"]
1: (28) ["1", "101", "m1", "fa fa-image", "", "", "N", "1", "101-01", "Account (ACC:ACC01)", "", "ACC:ACC01", "101", "Y", "1", "102", "m2", "fa fa-image", "", "", "N", "1", "102-01", "Account Details Listing (ACC:ACC05)", "", "ACC:ACC05", "102", "Y"]
2: (28) ["1", "101", "m1", "fa fa-image", "", "", "N", "1", "101-01", "Account (ACC:ACC01)", "", "ACC:ACC01", "101", "Y", "1", "102", "m2", "fa fa-image", "", "", "N", "1", "102-01", "Account Details Listing (ACC:ACC05)", "", "ACC:ACC05", "102", "Y"]
3: (28) ["1", "101", "m1", "fa fa-image", "", "", "N", "1", "101-01", "Account (ACC:ACC01)", "", "ACC:ACC01", "101", "Y", "1", "102", "m2", "fa fa-image", "", "", "N", "1", "102-01", "Account Details Listing (ACC:ACC05)", "", "ACC:ACC05", "102", "Y"]
```

I converted this array into JSON Obj by using `jsonItemChild.ID = MenuID;` and push this JSON into JSON Parent `jsonMenuItems.push(jsonItemChild);`. Yet, the result of JSON `jsonMenuItems` store only the last list item (m2) with its child.

I expected it store like this:

```
jsonMenuItems = [    {"ID"      :"1",
                    "ItemID"    :"101",
                    "ItemDesc"  :"m1",
                    "Icon"      :"fa fa-image",
                    "Form"      :'',
                    "Parents"   :'',
                    "Active"    :'Y'},
                    {"ID"        :"1",
                    "ItemID"    :"101-01",
                    "ItemDesc"  :"Account (ACC:ACC01)",
                    "Icon"      :"",
                    "Form"      :'ACC:ACC01',
                    "Parents"   :'101',
                    "Active"    :'Y'},
                    {"ID"      :"1",
                   "ItemID"    :"102",
                   "ItemDesc"  :"m2",
                   "Icon"      :"fa fa-image",
                   "Form"      :'',
                   "Parents"   :'',
                   "Active"    :'Y'},
                   {"ID"        :"1",
                   "ItemID"    :"102-01",
                   "ItemDesc"  :"Account Detail Listing (ACC:ACC05)",
                   "Icon"      :"",
                   "Form"      :'ACC:ACC05',
                   "Parents"   :'102',
                   "Active"    :'Y'},
                ];
```

How can I achieve result like above? Please test it detail in jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/1k5z8mst/) here. Thanks.

Comment: A terminology note:  JSON is a string representation of a javascript object, used to transport data over the network. You're not using any JSON here at all, you're just working with a plain old javascript object.

Comment: @DanielBeck, I used here is a format of JSON already. The way that my script was not communicating with server, I just want to simplify my question only. In deed, the script above was generated in JSON formate and sent to server for further processing before sending back to client. If I would post it all, it would be much more i need to explain, and others would be hard to understand as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the same object over and over again, while adding it to your array several times: when you do that be aware that those array elements all reference the *same* object, and so any change you make to that object before adding it again will immediately affect what the other array elements are referring to.

So make sure to create a *new* object before initialising its properties. Change this:

```
jsonItemParent.ID = MenuID;
// ...
jsonMenuItems.push(jsonItemParent);
```

To this:

```
jsonItemParent = {}; // *******
jsonItemParent.ID = MenuID;
// ...
jsonMenuItems.push(jsonItemParent);
```

The same should be done for the other object `jsonItemChild`.

Fixed [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1k5z8mst/1/).

Comment: to my bad, I forgot this, I thought of something would override old data with new. I had no idea beside creating a branch new JsonMenuItem (JsonMenuItem2, JsonMenuItem3...) which would be impossible if I have more than 10 of them. Anyway, thanks very much for your greate answer, you saved me. Cheer!! :)